# Laravel APIs return always 200 status code in response

Tags: php, laravel

I want to understand the path of the response tracking and identify the classes it traverses. I'm encountering an issue across all APIs where I consistently receive a status code of 200, regardless of the actual response status. I've verified that the response headers are initially set correctly with "Content-Type: application/json" by logging the response before it is returned to the requesting server. However, at some point, the header seems to change to "text/html" instead of "application/json." I'm looking for a way to debug this and determine at which stage the header modification occurs. Additionally, I'm curious if this issue might be related to the deployment on a GoDaddy server. Any insights or guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this matter would be greatly appreciated.

```
    public function login(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        $subject = 'Invalid information enetered.Please try again'; 
        $response = response()->negative_response(false,$subject, 404);
        $email = strtolower(trim(data_get($request,'email',null)));
        $password = data_get($request,'password');
        $input_language = data_get($request,"language",null);
        $language = $input_language == "EN" ? "english" : "spanish";
        $user_data = LoginPageUserDetail::where('email',$email)->first();
        $token_type = 'login';
        if($user_data)
        {
            if(password_verify($password,data_get($user_data,'password'))) {
                if($user_data->is_active == 1)
                {
                    $user_id = data_get($user_data,'id',null);
                    if(!$user_data->language)
                    {
                        $language_data =  UserLanguage::assignLanguageToUser($language);
                        $language_id = data_get($language_data,"id",null);
                        User::updateUserData($user_id,['language_id'=>$language_id]);
                    } 
                    $token_data =   Usertoken::addToken($user_id,$token_type);
                    $token = data_get($token_data,'token',null);
                    $user_data= new UserResource($user_data,$token);
                    $subject = 'Successfully Login';
                    $response =  response()->positive_response(true,$subject,$user_data,200);
                }
            }
        }
        CrewLog::saveLog($subject,$this->current_url,$this->current_function_name,$this->current_request_ip,$email);
        return $response;
    }
```

And this is the response

```
    public function boot(): void
    {
        Response::macro('positive_response', function ($error,$message,$data,$status_code) {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => $error,
                'message' => $message,
                'data'  => $data
            ], $status_code);
        });
    
        Response::macro('negative_response', function ($error, $message, $status_code) {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => $error,
                'message' => $message,
                'data'  => null
            ], $status_code);
        });
    }
```

Comment: There's an awful lot going on for a login controller and I don't really understand the sentiment for the macros, but looking beyond that, if you expect a JSON response from your Laravel API, you should use the `Accept: application/json` header and _not_ `Content-Type: application/json`.

Comment: I have two questions for you:
-- which provider hosts your macros?
-- also outgoing responses are handled in handler as well, so how about that?

The rest you have provided a bunch of unnecessary code but focusing on response i think it is okay if you can answer the above questions.

Comment: I'm using macro host as AppServiceProvider.  @shahsawood